# How to integrate Yii-auth in Yii-app?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I just created a Yii-App (from https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-app) with composer and it suggests Yii-Auth to manage Authentication, so I registered Yii-Auth and installed it, and I don't know how to integrate Yii-Auth in the Yii-App project (I wouldn't know how to integrate other extensions either), could someone guide me through the integration process, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Github page seems to be really detailed. https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-auth What happens if you just follow the README step-by-step? Check the chapter `Usage`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the steps on the Usage section refers when you installed the module in the protected/modules/auth (which is the path used on the regular Yii App, but I created a Yii-App (not the official, but the Crisu83's fork) which has a different folder structure (that's the reason of my question) all the extra modules,extensions,plugins are located in /../../vendor/(name of the extension,module,plugin)

Comment: Also, I saw that there are two classes that I can change the path that Yii uses to find them, but there is the module setting that I don't know how to point it to the vendor's folder.

Comment: `
return array(
  'modules' => array(
    'auth', <<<< This is the line I'm talking about, that I don't know how to replace.
  ),
  'components' => array(
    'authManager' => array(
      .....
      'behaviors' => array(
        'auth' => array(
          'class' => 'auth.components.AuthBehavior', <<<< Here I can set '(vendorfolder)crisu83.yii-auth.components.AuthBehavior'
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'user' => array(
      'class' => 'auth.components.AuthWebUser', <<<< Same Here '(vendorfolder)crisu83.yii-auth.components.AuthWebUser'
      'admins' => ....
    ),
  ),
);
`

Answer (score 0):

The strings `'auth.components.AuthBehavior'` and `'auth.components.AuthWebUser'` are path aliases. See the [definitive guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace) for more information on Yii path aliases.

The `'auth'` will be defined somewhere in this module. (I do not know where because I am not familiar with this particular module.) It would be cleanest to find the definition of the `'auth'` alias and change that to match your directory structure.

If you do not want to do that, you could replace the string with something like  '???.vendor.auth.components.AuthBehavior'. I do not know the exact alias, because I do not know your directory structure.

Hope this helps. If not, show you directory structure.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response, I think that "auth" is defined in:

 'modules' => array( 'auth' ),

And Yii already knows to look for the "auth" folder in the protected/modules folder (maybe something which is in the core code of Yii, I'll look for it).

I'll give it a try and let you know.

Thanks.

Comment: I found this:

`
Yii::setPathOfAlias('modules_sys', '/path/to/modules');

return array(
    // ...
    
    'modules'=>array('module1', 'module2',
        'module3'=>array(
            'class'=>'modules_sys.moduleName.moduleNameModule',
        ),
    ),
);
`

Here, http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26903-modules-in-multiple-directories/

I'll check this out later because I have to do some debugging right now, thanks.